# What is the difference between a pointer set to a value and a pointer set to the address of a value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I've got two questions, really. The first has to do with the interaction between a pointer and a variable, and the second has to do with the interaction between a pointer and an array. What is the best way to understand this?

I understand that a pointer contains the address to a variable, but I'm not sure what the difference is between setting the pointer to an address and setting the pointer to a variable.

I seem to have the same problem with an array, except more complex because an array may not just have one value.

For instance:

```cpp
int num = 5;
int * p;

p = num;  //This results in an error
p = &num; //This does not
```

Whereas:

```cpp
int num[2] = {5, 10};

p = num;  //This does not result in an error
p = &num; //This does
```

For the first situation, I get an error saying, "a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"".

For the second situation, I get an error saying, "a value of type "int (*)[2]" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int *"".

Why is this?

EDIT: I don't believe this to be a duplicate question. Array decaying does not answer my question at all, and instead this has to do with pointer types rather than properties of arrays. This question has been answered well already, but I would like to clarify that my issue was not answered by anything having to do with array decaying.

Comment: See a question about [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: To compare apples with apples, the second case should have `int(*p)[2]`, not `int *p`.  That is the type of the address of `num`. Then you would get the same pattern of error/non-error.

Comment: The difference is that 'a pointer set to a value' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: I consider that the identified duplicate is not actually a duplicate.   Array "decaying" is only one factor of several that is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable has a number of distinct properties.

Given your variable definition, which I quote here

> ```
> int num = 5;
> ```

its type is `int`, its name is `num`, it is initialised with a value of `5`, and its address (e.g. location in machine memory) is `&num`.

If I was to define a second variable immediately after

```
int q = 5
```

then this variable would (like `num`) have type `int`, and value `5`, but a different name `q` and a different address in memory `&q`.   Even though they have the same value, the addresses of `num` and `q` are different.  That (among other things) ensures that assigning `q = 6` does not change the value of `num`.

It goes further.   The pointer in your sample

> ```
> int * p;
> ```

means that `p` is a pointer to an `int`.   It has type `int *`, so its value can be the address of an `int`.  So the assignment

> ```
> p = num;  //This results in an error
> ```

doesn't work, because `p` has type `int *` and `num` has type `int`.   The two types are distinct,  and an `int` cannot be converted implicitly to an `int *`, so the assignment is not allowed.   They are different types.   In the real world, the street address of a house is something different from a house, even if there is an association between them.

However your assignment

> ```
> p = &num; //This does not
> ```

works, because `p` is of type `int *` and `&num` is the address of an `int` so also has type `int *`.

**However, with arrays, the rules are a little different.**

> ```
> int num[2] = {5, 10};
>
> p = num;  //This does not result in an error   
> p = &num; //This does
> ```

Firstly, `num` is an array of two `int`.  It has name `num`, but its type is `int[2]`, and its value is actually based on the pair of `int`s `5` and `10`.

When used in an expression, `num` is converted to a pointer to its first element.   So

```
p = num;
```

is equivalent to

```
p = &num[0];
```

The conversion of `num` to `&num[0]` is called an "array to pointer" conversion.

The second assignment you tried

> ```
> p = &num; //This does
> ```

is different.   In this case `&num` is the address of the array `num`, not the address of its first element.   So `&num` has type `int (*)[2]` which (in C++) syntactically means "pointer to an array of two `int`".

The type of `p` is `int *` (because that's how you defined it) whereas `&num` gies a result with type `int (*)[2]`.  Those types are different, so the assignment is invalid.

If you want a variable that points to an array of two `int` (as distinct from your `p` which can point at the first element of an array of `int`) then define

```
int num[2] = {5,10};
int (*q)[2];       //  q has type int (*)[2]

q = num;      // this will work
```

Then you can do, for example;

```
std::cout << (*q)[0] << ' ' << (*q)[1] << '\n';
```

to print the values `5` and `10`.    This works because `q` points at the array, `*q` is (a reference to) the array `num`,   so `(*q)[0]` and `(*q)[1]` access `num[0]` and `num[1]` respectively.

Note that the parentheses `()` are critical in all of the above discussion.    `*q[0]` is actually (by rules of operator precedence and associativity) equivalent to `*(q[0])` which is something quite different from `(*q)[0]`.    I'll leave working out what `*(q[0])` is (or is not) an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are a big hurdle to come across for new programmers.
Let me try to put it in the most easiest way I can.

Pointers are a data type in languages like C and C++ which point to a specific "memory location" specified by the pointer's type, meaning only a int pointer can point to a int memory location.

In your first example,

```
p = num
```

gives an error because you are trying to point the pointer to a value, but pointers cannot point to values but instead only memory locations. That is why

```
p = &num
```

works.

In your second example,

```
p = num
```

works because for arrays and structs in c and c++, setting the pointer directly to them automatically points to the first memory address specified by the array. 
Arrays are not special data types by themselves but rather sequences of values right after one another in memory.
But,

```
     p = &num
```

doesn't work because you are trying to point to the memory location of a memory location. num already points to the first location in the array, and &num points to the memory location of that location. That is why it's an error.
Hope you got it!